# -webkit-overflow-scrolling Problems With Objects Inserted Into DOM

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I'm using -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch for native scrolling capabilities on my iPad. But I've come into quite an odd problem:

I have one `div` with various children. If these children are big enough to create the need for scrolling, the device properly scrolls correctly, with momentum and all. However, if this div is not big enough to require scrolling, and suddenly has elements inserted into it and now does require scrolling, you will not be able to scroll the element at all.

I hope that wasn't too incredibly confusing, but if someone could shed some light on what to do in this situation, that would be fantastic. There isn't much documentation about this property out there.

EDIT: Tried testing this a lot, and it seems now it's just a generally intermittent problem. Every 1 out of 5 times or so, scrolling just fails for my entire web app, no matter the contents.

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to either your site, a jsfiddle, or codepen?

Comment: Did some more testing, seems like it is just a general intermittent problem with this property.

Comment: Yeah I'm having the same problem'ish. Different context but essentially `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` gets stuck from time to time (mostly on the iPhone 4 vs 4s). Have read everything i can possibly find online and it just seems like a wonky implementation in iOS so far. I think iOS6 is going to have some improvements from what i've seen in testing a bit. But if anyone has tips on refreshing a scrollable div that would be mega-helpful. Anyways, goodluck.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it seems like assigning the CSS class after the new DOM element is added seems to work fine:

```
// your code to add a div to the DOM
// the div contains a scrollable div with the content class
setTimeout(function(){
  // this is using JQuery
  div.find(".content").addClass("overflowScroll");
}, 1);

// CSS class
.overflowScroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

// The HTML for the div
// I am adding a dynamic list to the content div
// which should use the overflow scroll
<div class="panel">
  <div class="header">

  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```